# antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token, WHERE clause, and unexpected token

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, exception

I've already searched other problems related to this but I've just realized that maybe it's in the query of mine perhaps that this problem occurred or in the hibernate

SEE The where clause, it hasn't been called yet its there 
what could be the problem?

Here is the whole code
        try{
            //one by one check the select field
            String query = "Select emp.employeeID,emp.firstName,emp.middleName,emp.lastName,pos.positionName,dept.deptName,work.workplaceName"
                    +"from Employee emp "
                    + "INNER JOIN Department dept "
                        + "ON emp.departmentID = dept.deptID " 
                    + "INNER JOIN Position pos " 
                        + "ON emp.positionID = pos.positionID "
                    + "INNER JOIN Workplace work " 
                        + "ON emp.workplaceID = work.workplaceID ";

```
                if(checkAllNotEmpty(data)) {
                    query = query.concat("WHERE ");

                    if(data.getEmployeeID() != null && !data.getEmployeeID().equals("")) {  
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_EMPLOYEEID2);
                        System.out.println("Employee IDs");
                        input_empID = true;
                    } 

                    if(data.getEmployeeName()!= null && !data.getEmployeeName().equals("")){ 
                        criteria.add(nameCriteriaHelper(data.getEmployeeName()));
                        System.out.println("Employee Name AKOOO");
                        input_empName = true;
                    }

                    if(data.getDepartmentID()!=0) {
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_DEPARTMENT);
                        System.out.println("Dept ID ");
                        selected_dept = true;
                    }
                    if(data.getPositionID()!=0) {
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_POSITION);
                        System.out.println("POS ID ");
                        selected_pos = true;
                    }
                    if(data.getWorkplaceID()!=0) {
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_WORKPLACE);
                        selected_work = true;
                    }

                    query = query.concat(String.join(" OR ", criteria));
                }
                query = query.concat(" ORDER BY emp.joinDate DESC");
                System.out.println("QUERY: " + query);
                Query q = session.createQuery(query);
                if(input_empID) {
                    q.setParameter("id", "%" + data.getEmployeeID() + "%");
                }
                if(input_empName) {
                    if(searchbyOne)
                        q.setParameter("inputName", "%" + data.getEmployeeName() + "%");
                    if(searchbyFandL)
                        q.setParameter("firstLastName", "%" +firstLastName+ "%");
                    if(searchbyCompName)
                        q.setParameter("completeName", "%" +completeName+ "%");
                }

                if(selected_dept) {
                    q.setParameter("deptID", data.getDepartmentID());
                }
                if(selected_pos) {
                    q.setParameter("posID", data.getPositionID());
                }
                if(selected_work) {
                    q.setParameter("workID", data.getWorkplaceID());
                }
                employees = (List<Object>) q.list();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }

    return employees;
}
```

So Help T.T

Comment: Why no condition after `WHERE`? If not required any condition, why don't you remove it

Comment: the following conditions under the where clause is null yet the where clause still appears. That's exactly what I wanted to do (to delete the where clause), yet I do not know how ... there are conditions involved inside the where clause

Comment: You code is not enough .. update your question and show the code where the query is formed  and not the final result only  ..

Comment: You should remove `where` if conditions are not present or atleast put `where 1` with the conditions like 'AND [CONDITION]'.

Comment: Probably you posted the SQL output, but what we need - is code of HQL sentence, update your question